# Puzzled by something in .reduce() method (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reduce

in the next function where I use the reduce method in Javascript, I don't understand why I get different results when I use "current" or "array[index] in my if statement (inside my reduce method).

Aren't current and array[index] the same thing?

```
function pairwise(arr, arg) {

  return arr.reduce(function(acc,current, index, array){
    for(var i=index+1;i<array.length; i++){
      if(current+array[i]===arg){
        acc += index+i;
        array[index]=array[i]=NaN;
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, 0)

  }
```

Thank you !!

Comment: please add some data for the array and the call of the function and what you expect to get. and what you got.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I meant: aren't current and array[index] interchangeable inside if(current+array[i]===arg)?  I get a different result whether I put "current" or array[index] which is strange since for me they both represent the same thing.

Comment: without data and what you expect it' s hard to guess, what you want and what not work.

Answer (score 2):

You mean in this line?

```
array[index]=array[i]=NaN;
```

If you assign to `array[index]`, you're modifying the array.
If you assign to `current`, you're just overwriting the local variable `current`, but that doesn't have any lasting effect on the array from which that value came.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3],
    current = arr[0];

current = 42;  // obviously does not modify arr
arr[0] = 42;   // obviously modifies arr
```

Comment: No sorry,  I meant: aren't current and array[index] interchangeable inside if(current+array[i]===arg)?  I get a different result whether I put "current" or array[index] which is strange since for me they both represent the same thing.